# Extract PDF Content Including Images For RAG

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, information-retrieval, large-language-model, retrieval-augmented-generation

I am trying to build a PDF content extraction and chunking system for RAG in my application.
I need to include images from pdf as urls,so that the llm can use that images in the response
most of the solutions that i have seen only extract text content from pdf.Is there any way to extract images and text from pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

PyMuPDF allows you to do that for images and tables